# Variable partitioning of the data in the form of "list of lists"

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, interpolation, partitions

I am looking for a way for variable partitioning of the data in the form of a "list of lists" for interpolating the imported data from excel. The data looks like:

```
data = {
  {{5., 9.53333, 0.057735}, {5., 19.3333, 0.057735}, {5.,29.2667, 0.057735},
   {5., 39.0667, 0.11547}, {5., 49., 0.}, {10., 11., 0.}, {10., 22.4, 4.35117*10^-15}, 
   {10., 33.6667, 0.057735}, {10., 45.1, 0.}, {10., 56.3333, 0.11547},
   {15., 12.4667, 0.057735}, {15., 25.2667, 0.057735}, {15., 38., 0.1}, 
   {15., 50.9333, 0.057735}, {15., 63.7667, 0.057735}, {20., 13.8333, 0.057735}, 
   {20., 28.1, 0.1}, {20., 42.3667, 0.057735}, {20., 56.5333, 0.057735}, 
   {20., 70.8667, 0.152753}}
       }
```

Now I want to interpolated this data using `Interpolation` function but the problem is that `Interpolation` needs the data in the form:

```
{{5., 9.53333}, 0.057735}, {{5., 19.3333}, 0.057735},...}
```

Without bothering about this form, if I try to Interpolate using command:

```
f = Interpolation[data[[1]], InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

it interpolates but produces a warning as well:

> ```
>  Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only 
>  supported for InterpolationOrder -> 1 or InterpolationOrder -> All. 
>  Order will be reduced to 1.
> ```

I would have been happy if the 3D plot of `f[x,y]` would have been a bit better than this (I hate spikes in the plot):

[image: 3D plot when InterpolationOrder is 1]

Overall, I think that the problem can be resolved by supplying "structured grids" to the `Interpolation` command and that's where I have got stuck. I need to arrange the data as it is required in the `Interpolation` command. I have also checked Mr Wizard's solution for [dynamic partitioning]([Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size)"list manipulation - Partitioning with varying partition size") but it dose not work (or I must say - I could not make it work) in this case. I have got a feeling that some modification in that will do the job but I do not know the workaround for that.
So the question is how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I believe all you need is this:

```
newdata = {{#, #2}, #3} & @@@ data[[1]]
```

> ```
> {{{5., 9.53333}, 0.057735}, {{5., 19.3333}, 0.057735}, {{5., 29.2667}, 0.057735}, . . .
> ```

If your `data` contains multiple sets you can use the long form of [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) and the appropriate [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29752/121), here `{2}`:

```
newdata = Apply[{{#, #2}, #3} &, data, {2}]
```

Reference:

- [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html)
- [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html)
- [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)
- [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)

Comment: I must say that was quick. May be it was easy for you. Thanks a ton. c :)

Comment: @Om. You're welcome.  Yes, it was easy, but I spend way too much time playing with *Mathematica* syntax. :-)  I think you will find a lot of power in `Slot` (`#`, `#2`, etc.) which is used in `Function` (short form `&`), and `Apply`.  I use these functions all the time.  Sometimes they are not optimal due to [unpacking](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5258/121) but they are convenient and concise, therefore often my first approach.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to repartition the data. Here's one:

```
data2 = Flatten[data /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}, 1]
```

Then you can interpolate as before:

```
f = Interpolation[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Note that I have changed the order to 1 -- this is what the warning was telling you -- with data that is not on a regular grid, you cannot use order greater than 1. The jagged edges are then caused (not by the interpolation) but by the number of points used to plot. So changing the PlotPoints option makes it smoother:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 5, 20}, {y, 9.5, 70}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

As Mr Wizard points out, it might be safer to make sure that the replacement rule only applies to the numerical data, hence:

```
data2 = Flatten[data /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} -> {{x, y}, z}, 1]
```

would be safer.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this.  You could get a false match with the pattern `{x_, y_, z_}` causing a nasty bug.  You should make the replacement at a specific level or use `_?NumericQ`.  Please see: [(6543)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6543/121), [(7688)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7688/121), [(17497)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17497/121).

Comment: Elegant and perfect. I never used `Flatten` command like that. Great !! Don't mind it but I can't +1 the reply. Sorry to You, Mr Wizard and Artes. Thanks a lot to all of you. Cheers !! :)

Comment: Thanks for the caution Mr Wizard. Checking out the possibility !!

Comment: Now you get my +1.

Comment: Alas that's tragic!! I was looking for higher order Interpolation to smoothen the plot. :(

Comment: @Om. Have you seen these?: [(8458)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8458/121), [(20334)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20334/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ Flatten[data, 1]
```

or

```
d = {Most @ #, Last @ #}& /@ Flatten[data, 1]
```

e.g.

```
{Most@#, Last@#} & /@ Flatten[data, 1] // Short
```

> ```
> {{{5., 9.53333}, 0.057735}, <<18>>, {{20., 70.8667}, 0.152753}}
> ```

**Edit**

Given `data` allow only for `InterpolationOrder -> 1`

```
f = Interpolation[ d, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

To visualize `data` we can make use of various `options` of `Plot3D`.  To get a better resolution we rescaled `z`-axis using appropriate values of `BoxRatios`.

```
Plot3D[ f[x, y], {x, 5, 20}, {y, 14, 70}, PlotPoints -> 150,  MaxRecursion -> 4, 
        MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 30, ClippingStyle -> None, 
        ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", BoxRatios -> {15, 60, 5}, 
        ViewPoint -> {-1, -3, 1}]
```

[image]