# FirstPosition returning an error message together with the correct answer

Tags: pattern-matching, list-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
Module[{lst},
    lst = {
        {1, 37, 2, 22},
        {3, 59, 9, 9},
        {6, 1, 32, 56},
        {31, 42, 46, 27},
        {58, 38, 64, 47}
    };
    FirstPosition[lst, x_ /; (x[[2]] == 42)]
    (* Also tried the following, with the same result *)
    (* FirstPosition[lst, _?(x[[2]] == 42 &)] *)
]
```

The code is simple enough, but I get the following error message before getting the right answer:

[image: FirstPosition]

Can you please help me find the error?

Comment: Add the appropriate levelspec (or fix your pattern). Otherwise, your pattern matches more than you think.

Comment: @rasher Can you please provide the correct expression?  `FirstPosition[lst, x_ /; (x[[2]] == 42), 1, 1]` returns the first line of the error message above.

Comment: A simpler form that achieves the same result is `FirstPosition[lst, 42][[1]]`

Comment: `FirstPosition[lst, x_ /; (Length[x]>=2 && x[[2]] == 42)]`, or `FirstPosition[lst, x_List/; (x[[2]] == 42)]` if it is safe to assume al expressions are lists that have a length of at least 2.

Comment: It's not a bug, just a bit of a nuisance. You need to specify level 1 only, and no heads are to be checked. This first necessitates that you also provide a default value. `FirstPosition[lst, x_ /; (x[[2]] == 42), Missing["IWasAPoorlyDesignedArgument"], {1}, 
 Heads -> False]` should do what you want

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the suggestions.  If one of you would take the trouble to write your suggestion as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Related: [(6543)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6543/121)